# append html to the div with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can i pass html through in AngularJS controller ?

Here is my **list.html**:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="item in companyData"> 
     <a ng-click="getPackageInfo({{item.iCompanyID}},'{{item.vCompanyName}}')" class="block panel padder-v bg-primary item">
      <span class="text-white block">{{item.vCompanyName}}</span>
     </a>

    <div id="packagehtml"></div>
</div>
<div id="lp" class="col-md-12 listing-div hidden"></div>
```

in **controller.js**:

```
$scope.pData = [];
    $scope.getPackageInfo = function(id,name) {
        $scope.name = name;
        var summery = SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getSummary(id);
        document.getElementById("lp").classList.remove("hidden");
        $('.packages-data').html('');
        $('#loading').show();
        SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getPackageInDetail(id).
        success(function(data) {
            if(data != 0) {
                $("#lp").html(summery); // this is used to append the data
                document.getElementById("np").classList.add("hidden");
                Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.pData, data);
                $('#loading').hide();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("lp").classList.add("hidden");
                document.getElementById("np").classList.remove("hidden");
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    };
```

Here, I have wrote `$("#lp").html(summery);`, in that div I have to append html which comes from `var summery = SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getSummary(id);`. But this is not going to append the data. In console I can see that data comes in `summary` variable. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at below modifications

- Use angular `ng-show` for showing/hiding elements
- Use data binding and avoid Jquery like Dom manipulation

  ```
  <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="item in companyData"> 
      <a ng-click="getPackageInfo({{item.iCompanyID}},'{{item.vCompanyName}}')" class="block panel padder-v bg-primary item">
          <span class="text-white block">{{item.vCompanyName}}</span>
      </a>

      <div id="packagehtml"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="lp" ng-show="lbVisible" class="col-md-12 listing-div hidden">{{summaryBinding}}</div>
  ```

and the controller would look like :

```
    $scope.pData = [];
$scope.getPackageInfo = function (id, name) {
    $scope.name = name;
    var summery = SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getSummary(id);

    $scope.lbVisible = true; //document.getElementById("lp").classList.remove("hidden");

    $('.packages-data').html('');

    $scope.loadingVisible = true; //$('#loading').show();

    SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getPackageInDetail(id).
            success(function (data) {
                if (data != 0) {

                    $scope.summaryBinding = summery; //  $("#lp").html(summery); // this is used to append the data


                    $scope.npVisible = false; // document.getElementById("np").classList.add("hidden");

                    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.pData, data);
                    $scope.loadingVisible = false; // $('#loading').hide();
                } else {
                    $scope.lbVisible = false; //document.getElementById("lp").classList.add("hidden");
                    $scope.npVisible = false; //document.getElementById("np").classList.remove("hidden");

                    $scope.loadingVisible = false; // $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
};
```

your snippet is not showing elements that you use :

```
np, #loading  so just find them and add the `ng-show` with the proper scope variable : `npVisible , lbVisible , loadingVisible`
```

and note that we add the data using `summaryBinding`

hope this helps :)

Comment: let me try and get back

Comment: it just printing `{}`, nothing else. not printing `HTML`

Comment: try :
`<div id="lp" ng-show="lbVisible" class="col-md-12 listing-div hidden" ng-bind-html="summaryBinding"></div>`

instead of : 
`<div id="lp" ng-show="lbVisible" class="col-md-12 listing-div hidden">{{summaryBinding}}</div>`

and :

`$scope.summaryBinding = $sce.trustAsHtml(summery);`

instead of : 
`$scope.summaryBinding = summery;`


@hnn